# Error handling for "no manual entry" in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I just started learning bash scripting and I've been trying to create a script that'd print every man page to a pdf file. Problem is I don't know how to handle errors for 'no manual entry found' and the script just creates a blank file for commands that have no manual entry.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

declare -a commands

commands=(pwd cd ls mkdir rmdir echo)

for i in "${commands[@]}"
do
    man $i | pandoc --pdf-engine=pdfroff -o $i.pdf
done
```

Thanks in advance and I am sorry if it was a stupid question.

Comment: You could just delete the empty files at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man man`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      Successful program execution.
       ...
       16     At least one of the pages/files/keywords didn't exist or wasn't matched.
```

Check `man` exit status. `if` is the compound command that checks commands exit status. Assignment preserves exit status, you can assign and check at the same time.

```
if tmp=$(man "$i"); then
     <<<"$tmp" pandoc ....
else
     echo "Och nuuuu, there is no man page for $i" >&2
fi
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.